# Files in dictionary

Tags: python-2.7

I am stuck on my code..
My code must be able to distinguish between files in a dictionary, I have no idea where to start:

```
user_specs = { "file1":{"param_a":["plot1","plot2"],"param_b": ["plot2"]}, "file2":{"param_c":["plot3","plot1","plot2"] } }
```

I now have this but it just reads the first 'file1':

```
for file in user_specs.keys():
     file_exists=os.path.isfile("./data/{}".format(file))
if file_exists:
        for key in user_specs:
            for i in user_specs[key]:
                for j in user_specs[key][i]:
                       if len(dataset.dimensions.keys()) == 1 and dataset.dimensions.keys() == "time":
                        if j == "histogram": 
                            histogramplot(dataset.variables["time"][:])
                        elif j == "timeseries":
                            print "hi"
                        elif j == "spatialmap":
                            print ""
                        else:
                            print "{} does not contain any available plot types".format(i)
                            print ""
```

The 1 in `len(dataset.dimensions.keys()) == 1` means that it is a 1D array, I want to make it upto a 3d array but that is not needed for my question about the files in the dictionary

Comment: In your post, you had used `users_specs` in the initial definition. Whereas, in the code in the rest of the post you have use the term `user_specs` (Notice the difference `users..` vs `user..`. )

Answer (score 0):

In your post, you had used `users_specs` in the initial definition. Whereas, in the code below the definition of `users_specs`, you have used the term `user_specs` (Notice the difference `users..` vs `user..`.) I can't reproduce the full output of your code since I don't have access to your definition of `dataset.dimensions`. After incorporating the above mentioned change, I find that your code reads both the keys of `user_specs` (*i.e.* `file1` and `file2`). The below mentioned section of the code shows the same.

```
user_specs = { "file1":{"param_a":["plot1","plot2"],"param_b": 
["plot2"]}, "file2":{"param_c":["plot3","plot1","plot2"] } }

for keys in user_specs: 
    for i in user_specs[key]:
        for j in user_specs[key][i]:
            print keys, i, j

>>>file2 param_a plot1
>>>file2 param_a plot2
>>>file2 param_b plot2
>>>file1 param_a plot1
>>>file1 param_a plot2
>>>file1 param_b plot2
```

Comment: Thanks! Now my follow up question is, in this dictionary, the param_a, param_b, or param_c can have 3 different variables (time, lon or lat), however it's not known which variables are in which parameter. Would you know how I would be able to acces these data? My files are .nc if that helps!

Comment: @ProgrammNoob : Thanks. Can you please give an example of `time` , `lon` and `lat` variables. I wanted to see the differences. If possible, you can upload the files, and give the links.